# how to apply different custom function based on dataframe row values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function

I have following dataframe
`df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 'y': [1,2,3,4,1,2], 'v': [10, 8, 12, 18, -5, 10]})`

I defined two custom functions say func1 and func2 with the df as the input. Both functions return a dataframe which have two columns x1 and x2. The function calculations are pretty complicated hence I am not posting here. My question is how do I output a dataframe with x1 and x2 column such that when id=b, apply func1 and else apply func2 to get the x1 and x2 values?
I tried this code

`result=df.apply(lambda x: func(1) if df['id']=='b' else func2(x), axis=1)`

It gave me the error "the truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use `x` for test `b`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 
                   'y': [1,2,3,4,1,2],
                   'v': [10, 8, 12, 18, -5, 10]})
print (df)

def func(x):
    return (x['y'] * 10, x['y'] * 5)

def func2(x):
    return (x['y'] * 0.2, x['y'] * .5)

result=df.apply(lambda x: func(x) if x['id']=='b' else func2(x), 
                axis=1, 
                result_type='expand')
print (result)
      0     1
0  10.0   5.0
1  20.0  10.0
2  30.0  15.0
3  40.0  20.0
4   0.2   0.5
5   0.4   1.0
```

Comment: had a try but got this error msg "'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'"

Comment: @windvanish do you need `result=df.apply(lambda x: func(1) if (x['id']=='b').any() else func2(x), axis=1)`?

Comment: yes I need to output to excel eventually hence need to assign a variable

Comment: @windvanish - Answer was edited, alo added some sample. Can you test it?

Comment: I get the same error msg. my func1 and func2 is something like this:  `def aggreg_values(df):   
    a=[]  
    for _,g in df.groupby('id'):
        acc = 0
        reset=1
        for i,row in g.iterrows():
              if reset==1:
                  val=row['v']*0.1
                  reset+=1
                  a.append(val)
                  print (val)
              else:
                  val=row['v']*0.2
                  a.append(val)
                  print (val)
    return a`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function consisting of several functions. Then feed both id and the value you need to that function:

```
func_collective(id_,y_value,v_value):
   if (id_ == 'b'):
        return func1(y_value,v_value)
   if (id_ == 'a'):
        return func2(y_value,v_value) # functions 1 and 2 should have a return in form of "return [x1,x2]" if you wanna return two columns

df[['x1','x2']] = df.apply(lambda x: func_collective(x['id'],x['y'],x['v']), axis=1)
```

Comment: this is not so handy as the example is a simplified function. my df has more than 10 variables to pass to func1 and func2. is there a way to pass a df as the input to func1 and func2? I tried the following code but it didn't work.                                                              def func_collective(df):
    if df['id']=='b' :
        return func2(df)
    else:
        return func2(df)                                                                              result=df.apply(lambda x: func_collective(x), axis=1)

Comment: If you use df.apply(lambda x: func_collective(x), axis=1), then you have the entire row fed into the func_collective(x). Then inside the function you can use x['any_column_you_need']. Try axis=0 for that case too.

Comment: tried axis=0, the error msg is "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Comment: That axis=0 was a bad idea. Just tell me the error when you use axis=1 and this solution.

Comment: both cases gave the error msg as "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".